# AngularJS Empty Respose Using Spring Boot And Mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I have a `AngularJS` app where I take in user input and store it in a painting objects and then send it to my spring boot back-end that will store it to the `Mongodb` server and return an `id`, however when I try go POST anything to the server i get an empty response back, even though the object gets stored in the server.

AngularJS code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  URL : <input type="text" ng-model="painting.url"><br>
  Artist : <input type="text" ng-model="painting.artist"><br>
  ArtistInfo : <input type="text" ng-model="painting.artistInfo"><br>
  Title : <input type="text" ng-model="painting.title"><br>
  Dated : <input type="text" ng-model="painting.dated"><br>
  Medium : <input type="text" ng-model="painting.medium"><br>
  Dimensions : <input type="text" ng-model="painting.dimensions"><br>
  Credit : <input type="text" ng-model="painting.credit"><br>
  <button ng-click="submit()">Post</button>
  <pre>{{painting | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.name = "";
        $scope.painting = {
            url: '',
            artist: '',
            artistInfo: '',
            title: '',
            dated: '',
            medium: '',
            dimensions: '',
            credit: ''
        };
        $scope.submit = function(){
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.painting));
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/paintings',
                data: $scope.painting
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }, function (response) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.log((JSON.stringify(response)));
            });
            //$http.post('http://localhost:8080/paintings', $scope.painting).catch(console.error);
        };
    }]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

SpringBoot Java POST Method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/paintings")
public String save(@RequestBody Painting painting){
    repository.save(painting);
    System.out.println("Function called");
    return painting.getID();
}
```

PostMan Response:

[image: response]

Not sure why I'm getting an empty response when I check the console in a browser, even though the server is sending back a response.

Comment: @Claies when i run it in a browser and open the console i get an empty response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to access the data property of the response,

```
.then(function (response) {
   console.log(response.data);
 }
```

Comment: When i try to do that i get a value of undefined

Comment: can you post what do you get when you put console.log(response);

Comment: also stringify your json before post

Comment: this is what I get when i console.log(response.data +" "+ response.headers);
undefined undefined localhost:8080:59:17

Comment: yes i see an id number as the output, and i was also wondering why it would go to the error every time instead of the success, one error that i kept getting before was $http:baddata Bad JSON Data however i fixed it by creating a var name and stringifying painting into name and JSON.parse(name)

Comment: I was able to get a json response and it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing with the help of @Sajeetharan is edit my backend post request to

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/paintings")
public ResponseEntity<String> save(@RequestBody Painting painting){
    repository.save(painting);
    System.out.println("Function called");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("id",painting.getID());
    return  ResponseEntity.ok(json.toString());
}
```